# How to test web Service(Controllers functionality) in node.js Express, Sequelize app.Using stubs spy and mocks?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, sequelize.js, stubs

How to test web Service(Controllers functionality) in node.js Express, Sequelize app.Using stubs spy and mocks ?